# Recommended practice for creating local branch

Tags: git

When I create a local branch based on master, I have two options:

- Option 1: Create a local branch based on **local master**
- Option 2: Create a local branch based on **remote master**

**Background**

The problem I have the Option 1 is that I need to pull remote master into local master before I merge with my created local branch. On some senarios switching between branches confuses my IDE.

The reason that I like to consider option 2 is that I assume I can directly merge into remote\master withot being have to pull  it locally.

**Question**

With above background, which of the above two options work better when I need to merge my chnages back.

**Update 1**

@Code-Apprentice:

Considering fetch and Pull are not the same,

For option 1, I need to pull local master, so I can merge with local master

For option 2, only a a fetch would be sufficient, and I can do the merge with remote mster.

Am I correct?

Comment: Define "work the best". What are you trying to achieve/avoid?

Comment: @RomainValeri, I elaborated my question and added more context. Does it make sense?

Comment: Note that you in Option 2 will still have to `git fetch` to update your local copy of `remote/master`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, you are correct, but I do not have to pull the changes. Fetch and Pull are not the same. I think for oprion 1 I have to do a git pull on local master, but for Option 2 just a git fetch is sufficient. Am I correct?

Comment: @AllanXu Yes, git pull does more than git fetch does. My point here is that either way, you have to make sure that `master` or `remote/master` are up to date if other people are merging into them.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, I get your point. But remote\master is always updated automatically, whereas local master needs a pull to get the actual files.

Comment: I prefer to *avoid* `git pull` entirely. The pull command makes things obscure. Use separate `fetch` and second-commands; things are clearer that way, plus you'll know what command actually went wrong if the second command fails. Plus, you're now in complete control of the second command: if you want to `git merge origin/master`, you can just run `git merge origin/master`. If you want to run `git merge develop`, you can just run `git merge develop`. You're not at the mercy of `git pull` playing guessing games.

Comment: @torek, you have a good point and I agree. So do you think Option#2 should work better for me?

Comment: It probably will work better. Remember that what you're really doing here is choosing the *upstream* setting of the branch. The upstream gives you some convenience features, such as `git status` reporting things like "ahead 1" or "behind 12", and letting you run `git rebase` or `git merge` with no additional arguments. It also makes `git push`'s `simple` setting work.

Comment: @torek thank you!. Do you know if most people use Option#1 or Option#2? Which one do you use day to day work? I like to learn how most pople out there doing this type of things.

Comment: @torek, would you be able to create an answer, so I can upvote or mark answer?

Comment: I don't know what most people do. (I tend not to create branches the way I suspect most people do, for that matter.) Am a bit short on time right now though.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, creating a local branch from local master is the normal practice. But in those cases, it is expected that your local master is in sync with remote master.

Note that there is not one single best practice here. If the project/team has special needs, sometimes Options 2 might be better too.

Comment: I updated my question with more context. Does it make sense now?

Comment: You mentioned "In most cases," - do you know any article or document that explains the common practices?

Comment: Starting with https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/, the most popular branching model document, most places I have been practice merging to local, remote-tracking branches. Of course, there is no way to be certain which is objectively more common. Did you come across evidences of Option 2 being more common?

Answer (score 0):

Both options use the same number of commands:

Option 1:

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout -b feature123
```

Option 2:

```
git fetch
git checkout origin/master
git checkout -b feature123
```

Comment: Yes, but option#2 is much less impactful, since you do not have to pull all the remote files into local file system. Makes sense?

Comment: By saying impactful, I mean it doe not require a pull and to get files into local file system.

Comment: @AllanXu Oh...and the last two commands can be combined as a single `git checkout`, so my initial claim is incorrect.